# Value not passed to class - cannot resolve symbol

Tags: android

I had the value declared in onstartcommand in service.
Then i am unable to pass them to the displayingText in the run method. Any workaround?

1. Perhaps to optimize the timertask?
2. The declare global cannot be done, as public modifier is not allowed.
   Also, if i redefine the displayingText, it wont pass any value from the displayingText = intent.getStringExtra("PassToService");

MyService.java

```
public class MyService extends Service {
public static final long INTERVAL=3000;//variable to execute services every 5 second
private Handler mHandler=new Handler(); // run on another Thread to avoid crash
private Timer mTimer=null; // timer handling

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("unsupported Operation");
}
@Override
public void onCreate() {

}

private String displayingText;

public int onStartCommand (Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    String displayingText = intent.getStringExtra("PassToService");
    Toast.makeText(this, displayingText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    mTimer=new Timer(); // recreate new timer
    mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimeDisplayTimerTask(),0,INTERVAL);

    //return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    return START_STICKY;
}


@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
    stopSelf();///its will stop service
    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "In Destroy", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();//display toast when method called
    mTimer.cancel();//cancel the timer
    super.onDestroy();

}

//inner class of TimeDisplayTimerTask
private class TimeDisplayTimerTask extends TimerTask {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        // run on another thread
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // display toast at every 10 second
                final Toast Notify = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), displayingText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                Notify.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                Notify.show();

                Handler cancelToast = new Handler();
                cancelToast.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Notify.cancel();
                    }
                }, 1000);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: share all code...

Comment: @Anthony just declare  `String displayingText;` global .

Comment: You have to make _displayingText_ global.

Comment: as per answer by Ashwini Bhat
public modifier is not allowed.
Can you show how to make them global? Or return the value from getStringExtra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you don't declare in your `TimeDisplayTimerTask` class , you should use `displayingText` as global variable .

Try to use

```
String displayingText;

private class TimeDisplayTimerTask extends TimerTask {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        // run on another thread
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // display toast at every 10 second
                final Toast Notify = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), displayingText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                Notify.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                Notify.show();

                Handler cancelToast = new Handler();
                cancelToast.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Notify.cancel();
                    }
                }, 1000);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

And get value in your code .

```
public int onStartCommand (Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    displayingText = intent.getStringExtra("PassToService");
    Toast.makeText(this, displayingText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    // edited here ,change the return value 
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
```

**Edit**

Use Timer after `getStringExtra`

```
private String displayingText;

public int onStartCommand (Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    displayingText = intent.getStringExtra("PassToService");
    //SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs",MODE_PRIVATE);
    //String displayingText = prefs.getString("data","");
    Toast.makeText(this, displayingText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    // cancel if service is  already existed

    mTimer=new Timer(); // recreate new timer
    mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimeDisplayTimerTask(),0,INTERVAL);// schedule task
    //Intent intent = getIntent();
    //String displayingText = intent.getStringExtra("PassToService");

    return START_STICKY;
}


//inner class of TimeDisplayTimerTask
private class TimeDisplayTimerTask extends TimerTask {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        // run on another thread
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // display toast at every 10 second
                final Toast Notify = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), displayingText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                Notify.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                Notify.show();

                Handler cancelToast = new Handler();
                cancelToast.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Notify.cancel();
                    }
                }, 1000);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Edit**

You can test my code .And change something for yours .

```
public class MyService extends Service {

public static final String TAG = "MyService";
private Timer timer = new Timer();
private static final int UPDATE = 1;

private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
            case UPDATE:
                Log.d(TAG, "onStartCommand() executed");
                break;
        }
    }
};

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate() executed");
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Message message = new Message();
            message.what = UPDATE;
            mHandler.sendMessage(message);
        }
    }, 1000, 5000);
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy() executed");
    timer.cancel();
    timer = null;
}
```

Comment: The declaration String displayingText; will solve the symbol but still not passing the value to the code.
eg: The intent.getStringExtra will only work in onStartCommand.

Comment: You can check again.

Comment: check the google drive? i didnt see anything updated.

Comment: I can now compile the app, But the value still not passed to the toast within the timer

Comment: You can check it .

Comment: I added  the code I tested  .You can compare with yours .

Comment: thanks for your code. It does simplify my code for MyService.
But i still have a question. How do I change the message or get the message from the main activity using your code?

Comment: You can use EventBus.

Comment: thanks liuyue. Is it possible to to pass the value from the onstartcommand (intent.getstringextra) to the timertask into (your method /my method) without using eventbus if possible.
My aim are to write some messages in activity, pass them to service, then toast them every 5 sec. I like the switch case of yours, but i dont really know how to use them yet.

Comment: You can look some code for Handler And you can look for this .I was easy for using .[https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)

Answer (score 0):

Declare your string Globally

**instead of this line:**

```
String displayingText = intent.getStringExtra("PassToService");
```

**Use as:**

```
public String displayText;
displayingText = intent.getStringExtra("PassToService");
```

Comment: Error: modifier public not allowed here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
String displayText;

public int onStartCommand (Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
displayingText = intent.getStringExtra("PassToService");
Toast.makeText(this, displayingText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
return START_STICKY;
}

private class TimeDisplayTimerTask extends TimerTask {
@Override
public void run() {

    // run on another thread
    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // display toast at every 10 second
            final Toast Notify = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), displayingText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            Notify.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            Notify.show();

            Handler cancelToast = new Handler();
            cancelToast.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Notify.cancel();
                }
            }, 1000);

        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: if i redefine the displayingText, it wont pass any value from the displayingText = intent.getStringExtra("PassToService");

Comment: I had attached the full code. let me know your thinking. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you all for the help. I really appreciate them.
I had found a way to workaround the passing.
Instead of trying to keep returning the value as per KeLiuyue done for me. (a long discussion)
I had just tweaked a little as follow.

1. include a new variable.

> `private String serviceText;`

2. define the value in service for the new variable.

> ```
> public int onStartCommand (Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
>     String displayingText = intent.getStringExtra("PassToService");
>     Toast.makeText(this, displayingText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>     serviceText = displayingText;
> ```

Let me know if there's any suggestion.